How to import JSON data into R with one nested list?
I have a JSON file to be imported into R. Here is a section of the data:
{"data":[{"British Columbia":"BC","BC":"4.63"}, {"Alberta":"AB","AB":"4.15"}, {"Ontario":"ON","ON":"13.6"}]}

I need to turn this data into a dataframe, but the import is producing many NA values.
I tried the following:
library(jsonlite)
jsonData <- fromJSON("filepath")
jsonData

Output:
$data
  British Columbia   BC Alberta   AB Ontario   ON Manitoba   MB Saskatchewan   SK
1               BC 4.63    <NA> <NA>    <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA>         <NA> <NA>
2             <NA> <NA>      AB 4.15    <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA>         <NA> <NA>
3             <NA> <NA>    <NA> <NA>      ON 13.6     <NA> <NA>         <NA> <NA>
4             <NA> <NA>    <NA> <NA>    <NA> <NA>       MB 1.28         <NA> <NA>
5             <NA> <NA>    <NA> <NA>    <NA> <NA>     <NA> <NA>           SK  1.1

It appears to be because of the single term "data" at the beginning of the JSON file. How can I avoid this issue?
Desired output:
British Columbia BC
BC               4.63
Alberta          AB
AB               4.15
Ontario          ON
ON               13.6
Manitoba         MB
MB               1.28
Saskatchewan     SK
SK               1.1


In the call to jsonlite::fromJSON(...) add "simplifyVector = FALSE" so that the data is returned as a list.
Then unlist and convert to a data.frame
library(jsonlite)
library(tibble)

jsonData <- fromJSON('{"data":[{"British Columbia":"BC","BC":"4.63"}, {"Alberta":"AB","AB":"4.15"}, {"Ontario":"ON","ON":"13.6"}]}', simplifyVector = FALSE)

df<-as.data.frame(unlist(jsonData))
rownames_to_column(df)


                rowname unlist(jsonData)
1 data.British Columbia               BC
2               data.BC             4.63
3          data.Alberta               AB
4               data.AB             4.15
5          data.Ontario               ON
6               data.ON             13.6


Given x shown in the Note at the end, use fromJSON, extract the data portion, remove the NA's and convert the types to the correct ones.
library (jsonlite)
library (purrr)

x |>
  fromJSON() |>
  _$data |>
  map_dfr(na.omit) |>
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)

giving
# A tibble: 1 × 6
  `British Columbia`    BC Alberta    AB Ontario    ON
  <chr>              <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1 BC                  4.63 AB       4.15 ON       13.6

Note
x <- '{"data":[{"British Columbia":"BC","BC":"4.63"}, {"Alberta":"AB","AB":"4.15"}, {"Ontario":"ON","ON":"13.6"}]}'

